# Proper syntax for loading/exporting react components?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs and am unable to debug this error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Map`.

Here is the code:

Map.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { GoogleMapLoader, GoogleMap, Marker } from 'react-google-maps'


class Map extends Component {
    render(){
        const mapContainer = <div style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}></div>

        return (
            <GoogleMapLoader
                containerElement = { mapContainer }
                googleMapElement = {
                    <GoogleMap
                        defaultZoom={15}
                        defaultCenter={this.props.center}
                        options={{streetViewControl: false, mapTypeControl: false}}>
                    </GoogleMap>
                } />
        )
    }
}

export default Map
```

Places.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Places extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                Helloljlk
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Places
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Map from './components/Map'
import Places from './components/Places'

class App extends Component {
    render(){
        const location = {
            lat: 40.7,
            lng: -73.98
        }

        return (
            <div>
                Hello
                <div style={{width: 300, height: 600, background: 'red'}}>
                    <Map center={location} />
                </div>

                <Places />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

I've looked up similar issues but haven't been able to find anything that works i.e. removing {} from import statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component `GoogleMapLoader` has been deprecated in the version 6 onwards (please refer to the changelog [here](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)). So if you are using that version, you will get undefined when you import `GoogleMapLoader`. Instead, you should now be using `withGoogleMap`.

**Map.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { GoogleMapLoader, GoogleMap, Marker } from 'react-google-maps'

const Map = withGoogleMap(props => (
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={15}
    defaultCenter={props.center}
    options={{streetViewControl: false, mapTypeControl: false}} />
));
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Map from './components/Map'
import Places from './components/Places'

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    const location = {
      lat: 40.7,
      lng: -73.98
    }

    const mapContainer = <div style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}></div>;

    return (
      <div>
        Hello
        <div style={{width: 300, height: 600, background: 'red'}}>
          <Map 
            center={location}
            containerElement={mapContainer}
          />
        </div>

        <Places />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```